# php laravel array_merge key value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Hi I am creating an array which will store sections in my site. Some of these sections will not be available for some users to view therefore I will need to check the permission of the user in question before putting into my array. However when I do this if statement I get an array within an array which I don't want and this causes the following error:

`Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception`

This is the code I am using:

```
$user = Auth::user(); 
 if(($user->hasRole('Admin') || $user->hasRole('Admin') || $user->hasRole('Project Master') || $user->hasRole('Project Owner'))) {
  $restrictsections = ['Create' => route('project.create'),
                       'Sort' => route('project.sort'),];
  }

$this->sections = [
    'Projects' => [
        'View' => route('project.index'),
        $restrictsections

    ]
];
```

The array is now structured as so:

```
array(1) {
  ["Projects"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Create"]=>
    string(30) "http://projects.local/projects"
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Create"]=>
      string(37) "http://projects.local/projects/create"
      ["Edit"]=>
      string(35) "http://projects.local/projects/sort"
    }
  }
}
```

As opposed to:

```
  $this->sections = [
        'Project' => [
            'View' => route('project.index'),
            'Create' => route('project.create'),
             'Sort' => route('project.sort'),
        ]
    ];


array(1) {
  ["Project"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["View"]=>
    string(30) "http://projects.local/project"
    ["Create"]=>
    string(37) "http://projects.local/project/create"
    ["Sort"]=>
    string(35) "http://projects.local/project/sort"
  }
}
```

Any ideas how I can merge the two arrays together? but it should be structured as follows:

```
array(1) {
  ["Project"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["View"]=>
    string(30) "http://projects.local/project"
    ["Create"]=>
    string(37) "http://projects.local/project/create"
    ["Sort"]=>
    string(35) "http://projects.local/project/sort"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try array_merge_recursive

Comment: please echo "<pre>".print_r($array);  its so hard to read...

Comment: @rohitarora nope didn't work. still the same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+` operator to combine arrays.

For example:

```
php > print_r(['View' => '1'] + ['Create' => 'two', 'Sort' => '3']);
Array
(
    [View] => 1
    [Create] => two
    [Sort] => 3
)
```

Applying to your code:

```
$user = Auth::user(); 
 if(($user->hasRole('Admin') || $user->hasRole('Admin') || $user->hasRole('Project Master') || $user->hasRole('Project Owner'))) {
  $restrictsections = ['Create' => route('project.create'),
                       'Sort' => route('project.sort'),];
  }

$this->sections = [
    'Projects' => [
        'View' => route('project.index')
    ] + $restrictsections
];
```

edit: `+` is technically a union so if the second array has keys that are present in the first array they will be ignored.

Comment: thanks that works, if a user doesn't have anyone of these roles I get this error `Unsupported operand types`, any ideas why and how I can escape this error??

Comment: Initialize `$restrictsections` to an empty array before your if statement so that it isn't assumed `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Create it a little another

```
$this->sections = ['Projects' =>  $restrictsections];
$this->sections['Projects']['View'] = route('project.index');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge()` like this

```
$this->sections = [
    'Projects' => array_merge(
        ['View' => route('project.index')],
        $restrictsections
    )
];
```

or use the `+` operator like this

```
$this->sections = [
    'Projects' => ['View' => route('project.index')] + $restrictsections
];
```